# Using memcpy to copy the content of a dynamic array onto another produces a runtime error

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, stack, allocation

So I am trying to create a stack with a dynamic size, meaning that the capacity of the stack will change dynamically as needed. The concept worked out flawlessly in my head, create a function name `memoryManagement(int i)` that takes the size of data currently stored in the stack by a variable called `usedCapacity`. After this, the program was supposed to create a new array, use `memcpy` to copy the contents of the old array onto the new one. And finally, copy the contents of the new array back onto the old one with a new capacity. However, I keep getting a runtime error when I run my program. Also, depending in where I call the `showStack` function I sometimes get thrash numbers instead of the actual values I pushed onto the stack. If anyone could point me out on what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    //stack functions
    Stack();
    void push(int a);
    int pop();
    int peek() const;
    void showStack();
    ~Stack();
    //memory management
    void memoryManagement(int a);
    //void setCapacity(int  );
    //void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity);
private:
    int top;
    int * arr;
    int capacity;
    int usedCapacity;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {

    Stack calc;
    calc.push(11);
    calc.push(33);
    calc.showStack();
    calc.push(23);
    calc.push(43);

    return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Stack::Stack()
{
    top = -1;
    usedCapacity = 0;
    capacity = 1;
    arr = new int[capacity];
}

void Stack::push(int a)
{
    if (top > capacity)
        throw "Stack overflow";
    top++;
    usedCapacity++;
    arr[top] = a;
    memoryManagement(usedCapacity);
}

int Stack::pop()
{
    if (top <= -1)
        throw "Stack underflow";
        arr[--top];
}

int Stack::peek() const
{
    return top;
}

void Stack::showStack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    delete[] arr;
}

void Stack::memoryManagement(int a)
{
    if (a >= capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity;
        newCapacity = (a * 3) / 2 + 1;

        int * arr2 = new int[newCapacity];
        memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(int) * usedCapacity);

        delete[] arr;
        arr = arr2;
        delete[] arr2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The custom-made queue class apparently uses three indexes: top, capacity, and usedCapacity. I didn't bother trying to unravel the overcomplicated logic, but whatever it's trying to do, it's doing it wrong. This kind of a queue implementation never needs more than two indexes.

Comment: With `delete[] arr2`, you are essentially deallocating the memory block pointed by `arr`!!! BTW, a simple count reveals one occurrence of `new` and two occurrences of `delete`. That by itself should ring some alarm bells...

Comment: If there is a `delete`, there is probably a bug. If there is a naked `new`, there should be a `delete`. -> Don't do manual memory management in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you deleting `arr2` from `memoryManagement`? You should not, as that's apparently your new class attribute (you did `arr = arr2`):

But that's not enough (your program will then start throwing exception upon `push`....because you also forgot to modify your `capacity` attribute. Here is your working `memoryManagement` function:

```
void Stack::memoryManagement(int a)
{
    if (a >= capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity;
        newCapacity = (a * 3) / 2 + 1;

        int * arr2 = new int[newCapacity];
        memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(int) * usedCapacity);

        delete[] arr;
        arr = arr2;
        capacity = newCapacity; // Don't forget that!
        //delete[] arr2;        // Don't do that!
    }
}
```